# Correct solution for "multiple definition of" compile error

Tags: c

I'm in the process of trying to take [this demo sketch](https://github.com/tdicola/CloudThermometer/tree/master/CloudThermometer) and extract the necessary bits into a modular library that can be included in other sketches.

[Here's where I'm at so far](https://github.com/maketronica/Adafruit_CC3000_Dynamodb/tree/2ed5c6c8e251be4c0993ed0a1d68a85abe71d62d).

Here's [the test sketch](https://github.com/maketronica/cc3000test/blob/d22022cb76c2dbc92547a1ce7bca0fe97e106a6b/cc3000test.ino) that I'm including it in.

However, when I try to compile it right now, I'm getting...

```
libraries/Adafruit_CC3000_Dynamodb/sha256.cpp.o: In function `Sha256Class::init()':
/home/me/sketchbook/libraries/Adafruit_CC3000_Dynamodb/sha256.cpp:33: multiple definition of `Sha256Class::init()'
sketch/sha256.cpp.o:sketch/sha256.cpp:33: first defined here
```

I've been programming for years in other languages, but I'm not all that experienced in C. I'm sure I'm doing something completely stupid, but I can't figure out what it is.

I'm also aware that this code still needs a lot of cleanup work in general. Right now I'm just trying to work toward a basic MVP that works so that I start gradually cleaning things up and making it more OOP one step at a time.

Comment: It looks to me like you have a copy of the sha256.cpp file in your sketch which is causing the problem.

Comment: @Majenko , nope, but seeing the sketch would probably be useful... I'll get that into a repo and update the Q.

Comment: The error message tells me you have. "sketch/sha256.cpp.o:sketch/sha256.cpp:33: first defined here"

Comment: But I'm not sure how to interpret that.  I only have one each of sha256.cpp and sha256.h, and I'm only including sha256.h from one place.  I added a link to the sketch I'm using to test above.

Comment: The module sha256.cpp (and I think the sha256.h too) are already present. Remove these 2 files from the sketch directory and it should compile without errors.

Comment: @ott  No, they're not.  There's only one of each and they're in the library, not the sketch.

Comment: Which of the myriad of DHT libraries are you using?

Comment: They may be left over in the build folder. Try restarting the IDE

Comment: @Majenko BAM!  Restarting the IDE was it.  I learned something new today!  If you want to make that an actual answer, I'll accept it.  RE: the DHT library... ( https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library.git )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an old copy of the sha256 files lingering in the build folder. These will have been output at some point in the past and never been cleaned up since they have been deleted from the IDE.

It is probably a bug in the IDE that doesn't remove the old files.

Restarting the IDE will cure the problem and allow you to compile.